# Android send image with httpPost to a Servlet multipart

Tags: android, jakarta-ee, servlets, multipart, servlet-3.0

I try to send an image to using the multipart, like I read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2937140/1552648 but when it arrive to the servlet it doesn't take any thing.

Here is the android java code, where I send some text and the image that I have the IMG_URL from de SD card

```
private void enviarAlServidorConFoto(Incidencia incide, String IMG_URL){

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlservidor + "AnyadirIncidenciaAndroid");

    try {
        //MultipartEntity multiPart = new MultipartEntity();
        MultipartEntity multiPart = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        multiPart.addPart("usuario", new StringBody(incide.getUsuario()));
        multiPart.addPart("latitud", new StringBody(incide.getLatitud()+""));
        multiPart.addPart("longitud", new StringBody(incide.getLongitud()+""));
        multiPart.addPart("descripcion", new StringBody(incide.getDescripcion()));
        multiPart.addPart("tipo", new StringBody(incide.getTipo()));
        // YA la pongo desde la web a normal postParametros.add(new BasicNameValuePair("prioridad", value));
        multiPart.addPart("foto", new StringBody(incide.getFoto()));
        //no se pasa el nombre de la foto, puesto que ya lo extraera cuando se mande la foto sola
        multiPart.addPart("FotoIncidenciaAndroid", new FileBody(new File(IMG_URL)));

        httpPost.setEntity(multiPart);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{    
        HttpResponse res = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        res.getEntity().getContent().close();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("EnviadoAweb", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Then, here is the servlet with multipart also.

```
@WebServlet(name="AnyadirIncidenciaAndroid", urlPatterns={"/android/AnyadirIncidenciaAndroid"}, loadOnStartup=1)
```

@MultipartConfig(location="c:\temp", fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024, maxFileSize=1024*1024*5, maxRequestSize=1024*1024*5*5)
public class AnyadirIncidenciaAndroid extends HttpServlet {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -6704540377265399620L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public AnyadirIncidenciaAndroid() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    final String usuario = request.getParameter("usuario");

    System.out.println("Usuario recuperado al dar la incidencia desde movil: " + usuario);

    IncidenciaDAO idao = new IncidenciaDAO();
    Timestamp fechaalta = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Timestamp fechafin = null;
    double latitud = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("latitud"));
    double longitud = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("longitud"));
    String descripcion = request.getParameter("descripcion");
    String tipo = request.getParameter("tipo");
    String estado = "Nueva";
    String prioridad = "Normal";
    String empleado = null; //al tratarse de una incidencias nueva, aun no tenemos ningun empleado que la halla resuelto
    String foto = request.getParameter("foto");
    String nombrefoto = null;

    /* 
     * Si tenemos foto creada en la aplicacion movil, entonces tendremos que guardar el nuevo
     * nombre de la incidencia, en caso, de no tener foto, pondremos una string vacio,
     * y pondremos la imagen por defecto de sin imagen.
     */
    Part p1 = request.getPart("FotoIncidenciaAndroid");

    if(foto.equalsIgnoreCase("Si")){
        try {
            nombrefoto = idao.RenombrarFoto();
            // guardamos la foto con su nombre
            p1.write(nombrefoto);
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        idao.anyadirIncidenciaMapaWeb(fechaalta, fechafin, latitud, longitud, descripcion, tipo, estado, prioridad, usuario, empleado, foto, nombrefoto);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

How I have to do to take from what I send from de request?
Because that show me that the variable usuario is null

final String usuario = request.getParameter("usuario");
System.out.println("Usuario recuperado al dar la incidencia desde movil: " + usuario);

Also the log fomr the server say that it can make the request because what it send it's not a multipart

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am using these components to send images over to my server:

```
    public static void uploadPhoto(Uri imageUri, Activity activity, String restaurantId, String itemId) throws Exception{
    File imageToUpload = convertImageUriToFile (imageUri, activity);
    executeMultipartPost(imageToUpload.getAbsolutePath(),restaurantId, itemId);
}
```

where imageUri is the full path to image on:

Image converter:

```
    public static File convertImageUriToFile(Uri imageUri, Activity activity) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION };
        cursor = activity.managedQuery(imageUri, proj, // Which columns to
                                                        // return
                null, // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                null, // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
        int file_ColumnIndex = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        Log.v("App engine Manager", "File colum index:"+file_ColumnIndex);
        //  int orientation_ColumnIndex = cursor
        //  .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //String orientation = cursor.getString(orientation_ColumnIndex);
            return new File(cursor.getString(file_ColumnIndex));
        }
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Server Com:

```
    public static void executeMultipartPost(String path, String restaurantId, String itemId) throws Exception {
    try {

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        String URL = "", imageId = "";

        URL = "your server's URL to handle multipart data ";
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(URL);
        ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, imageId+".jpg");
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        reqEntity.addPart("uploaded", bab);
        reqEntity.addPart("photoCaption", new StringBody("sfsdfsdf"));
        postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String sResponse;
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

        while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            s = s.append(sResponse);
        }
        System.out.println("Response: " + s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle exception here
        Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: You have post the same code I posted, me trouble is with the servlet that doesn't make de request. Thanks.