# How to authenticate a user to a remote server in Android?

Tags: android, html, authentication

I've been making stand-alone Android apps for some time now, but I now want to make an app that requires authentication and have no idea where to start.

For example I would need to do the following:

1. Allow a user to create a new account, which would be stored in a remote server.
2. The user can log in to his account, and create journal-like entries (photos + text) which would be stored in the remote server.
3. The user's previous entries would be downloaded when he logs in.

Can you point me in the right direction?

I already know how to do all this in plain'ol HTML/PHP. Would a web app be a better idea, compared to native?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [tutorial on making a login screen](http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-login-screen-using-httpclient.html) for an android app that connects to a remote server.

You would probably use a similar post method to send more data to the remote server such as photos and text. [Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935946/sending-images-using-http-post) a good method of sending images to a server.

[Here's a nice method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview) of lazy-loading images in from a URL.

I hope this `pointed you in the right direction`!

---

Personally, I would prefer a web-app, because what you're making is heavily web-based, and by making an app only on android, you are shutting out users with other smartphones that would be able to use a web-app.