# POSTing an image to PHP file

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to POST an image to a PHP file from my android app and am wondering what format (File, Fileoutputstream etc) I have to post it in for it to be recognized as a file and refer to it with $_FILE['filename'] in my php script.

Thanks :)

**EDIT:**

Sorry I may not have been clear, I'm not looking for the PHP script, I already have that finished accepting the $_FILE['sample'] and doing what I need with it, I'm just not sure the file TYPE that I have to post to the php file (IN JAVA) in order for php to 'see' it as $_FILE

FYI: I am using the loopj asynchronous http request library.

```
public void add_image_android(final Bitmap image, String party_id, String guest_id) 
    { 

        String url = "http://www.mysite.com/urltopost";

            /* not sure what to set fOut to for the bitmap to be passed as file */

        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("file", fOut);
        params.put("guest_id", guest_id);
        params.put("party_id", party_id);
        client.post(url, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONObject response)
            {
                ((ResponseListener)_mainContext).add_image_android_response(response.toString());
                return; 
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e) 
            {
                fireToast("api error:"+e);
                Log.d("api error:",e.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show the Android code that you have so far, particularly the code that does the HTTP POST to the PHP server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uploading an image from Android (with Android Asynchronous Http Client) to rails server (with paperclip)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245469/uploading-an-image-from-android-with-android-asynchronous-http-client-to-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Try the Below Code which will upload the Image and Give the Link.

```
<?php
$uploaddir = 'images/';
$ran = rand () ;

$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir .$ran.$file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "http://www.domain.com/folder/{$uploadfile}";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: (very old code, hope it helps...)

```
ReturnObject returnObject = new ReturnObject(); 

HttpURLConnection conn = null;
DataOutputStream dos = null;
BufferedReader inStream = null;

String lineEnd = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary =  "*****";

int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;

byte[] buffer;

int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

String urlString = "your url";

try{
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(photoFile);

    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);

    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

    dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\";"
      + " filename=\"" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath() +"\"" + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0){
        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    fileInputStream.close();
    dos.flush();
    dos.close();

}catch (MalformedURLException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}catch (IOException ioe){
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

On the server i found this:

```
$source = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($source, $target)
```

Not sure what this "tmp_name" is...

Comment: sorry I cant use this method as I'm doing this request on the main thread which is why I needed to use the async library. Thanks though.
oh PS - $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; is where php saves the posted image temporarily, then you always move it to where you want it to be stored, in this case $target. :P