# Upload a file plus string from android to server not working

Tags: php, android, file, upload, webserver

I would like to upload a file from android device to server using php. Also I want to send the name of the file to a database with a WHERE statement. I can upload my file, but I can't send the WHERE statement, I don't know where and how to put it in the android source.

Here's my php code:

```
<form action="FileUp.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>

<?php

mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
mysql_select_db('db');

$target_path  = "./";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
$file = basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)){
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
" has been uploaded";
} else{
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
$ident=addslashes($_POST['ident']);

mysql_query ("UPDATE table SET column = CONCAT(column,'$file') WHERE id = '$ident'");

?>
```

And here's the java code:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String exsistingFileName = file.getText().toString();
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            try {
                // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST

                Log.e(Tag, "Inside second Method");

                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                        exsistingFileName));

                // open a URL connection to the Servlet

                URL url = new URL(urlString);

                // Open a HTTP connection to the URL

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoInput(true);

                // Allow Outputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                // Don't use a cached copy.
                conn.setUseCaches(false);

                // Use a post method.
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos
                        .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: post-data; name=uploadedfile;filename="
                                + exsistingFileName + "" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                Log.e(Tag, "Headers are written");

                // create a buffer of maximum size

                int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                int maxBufferSize = 1000;
                // int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesAvailable];

                // read file and write it into form...

                int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bytesAvailable = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);
                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // close streams
                Log.e(Tag, "File is written");
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                Log.e(Tag, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }

            catch (IOException ioe) {
                Log.e(Tag, "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn
                        .getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.e("Dialoge Box", "Message: " + line);
                }
                rd.close();

            } catch (IOException ioex) {
                Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
            }
```

Please help where do I need to put my ident string to send to the php side!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload the Images via the `MultipartEntity`.

`MultipartEntity`, part of `HttpMime 4.0` and later. Allows you to put multiple parts, separated by boundary strings and encoded using given charset, into httppost request.

For more info and how to use Multipart, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935946/sending-images-using-http-post) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017414/post-multipart-request-with-android-sdk).

Comment: Thank You for Your reply! It's a good solution, but for me it doesn't work. Everytime I get Dalvik error, and I've already tried the tricks suggested... So I make to requests, it's not elegant, but works.
Thanks!

Comment: I thought that that jar files caused the Dalvik problem, but didn't. It occures everytime, and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I've fixed the problem and now it works with Your solution. Sorry for it and thanks for Your help!