# Android HttpClient: sending a post request with MultipartEntity or Entity

Tags: android, entity, http-post, multipartentity

Basing on [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002547/android-httppost-with-parameters-and-file) I have learnt which I must use MultipartEntity in order to send an http post request with a body and parameters.

What I don't know is: once the request arrives on server side, does it have to manage in a different way the requests with a multipart entity and those with just an entity?

This question because I am developing a library and I have to choose how to send post requests to a server, if I can always use MultipartEntity (which is more general) or if I have to let the user to choose what to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You talk about "the server" as if all servers are the same.  I know from experience that some servers will require you to handle it differently though.  In my case I'm thinking of Java+Tomcat+apache-httpcommons

In short, yes, some servers will require it to be handled differently.

Comment: Ok, I told generally because I don't know if a specific server manages it differently. This response is sufficient to let me take a choice. Thanks!

Comment: @Massimo Ah.  Glad to hear it.