# Image can't save validable in android

Tags: android

I'm saving the images to mysql database using PHP. The images reach to the save file and database but they are in invalid format.Can't open. How to store image in correct method. Show me some ways. Here is my code.

```
 Bitmap bm = ShrinkBitmap(picturePath, 300, 300);
            resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 100, 100, true);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
            resizedbitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
            byte [] arr=baos.toByteArray();
            imageSave = Base64.encodeToString(arr, Base64.DEFAULT);

            img_Photo.setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);



 Bitmap ShrinkBitmap(String file, int width, int height){

     BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);

        int heightRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight/(float)height);
        int widthRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth/(float)width);

        if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1)
        {
         if (heightRatio > widthRatio)
         {
          bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
         } else {
          bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio;
         }
        }

        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);
     return bitmap;
    }



 postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photo", imageSave));
```

Edit: Here is PHP.

```
 if(isset($_POST["photo"]) && !is_null($_POST["photo"]))
                    {
                        $data = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["photo"]);   
                        //create folder
                        if(!file_exists('User_Photo/'))
                        {
                            mkdir('User_Photo/', 0777, true);
                        }
                        //upload image
                        define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'User_Photo/');
                        $img = $data;
                        $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
                        $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
                        $data = base64_decode($img);
                        $file = UPLOAD_DIR . $str . '.png';
                        $query .= "       , v_photo";
                        $value .= "       , '".$file."'";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $flag = true;
                    }
```

Comment: You save the images as base64 encoded strings. How do you know they are not valid, could you show us the decoding code?

Comment: I already posted decode file. ShrinkBitmap(picturePath, 300, 300);

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, you open an image in your Android app, call `ShrinkBitmap`, then post it to the server. How do you know they are in invalid format? I guess you display them on some webpage from PHP, that is the code I asked for.

Comment: The image reached to the saved file but when I open the image, it show black image only. I didn't saved black image but I don't know why they changed black image.

Comment: postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photo", imageSave)); This is the part to save PHP.

Comment: You just write the string received in POST to a file? It is base64 encoded, so of course it is invalid... I asked for the PHP code.

Comment: You want to say imageSave = Base64.encodeToString(arr, Base64.DEFAULT); is something wrong. So, what should I do?

Comment: Posting an image as string makes no sense: base64 actually increases its size, and your string escaping/replacements can corrupt it. Just [post the file itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002547/android-httppost-with-parameters-and-file).

Comment: Can I save Image path only?