# upload an image (bitmap) on a website with android and get an url back

Tags: android, url, bitmap

I'm what to upload an image (bitmap) from my android code to a website and get an url back. is there a simple api that i can use or how do i do it?

This is the Main Activity that takes a photo and puts it in a bitmap:

```
private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 100;
private static final int TAKE_PHOTO = 101;
static Bitmap yourSelectedImage;
ImageView im;
Uri imageUri;

/***
 * Sets up the layout an puts onClickListener() on the buttons
 * 
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
/***
 * Change intent on the buttons you click
 */
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO); 
        break;
        case R.id.button2:
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO);
        break;
    }
}

/***
 * Puts the image you choosed on the bitmap that you going to paint.
 */

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case SELECT_PHOTO:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            InputStream imageStream = null;
            try {
                imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

            Intent in = new Intent(this,EditPicsActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);

        }
        break;
    case TAKE_PHOTO:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Bundle extras = imageReturnedIntent.getExtras();
            yourSelectedImage = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

            Intent in = new Intent(this,EditPicsActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Heres the code that do changes in on the bitmap:

```
public class EditPicsActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

EditView edit;
float x,y;
Paint paint = new Paint();
float radius = 10;
ArrayList<painting> whatYouEdit = new ArrayList<painting>();
Canvas canvas1;

/***
 * Sets up the surfaceview
 */

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    x=y=0;
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    edit = new EditView(this);
    edit.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setContentView(edit);
    edit.Start();
}

/***
 * Sets up the menu window
 */
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_edit_pics, menu);

    return true;
}


/***
 * Do things when you press an option in your menu window
 */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.Brush_Blue:
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    break;
    case R.id.Brush_Green:
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    break;
    case R.id.Brush_Red:
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    break;
    case R.id.Brush_Black:
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    break;
    case R.id.Brush_5:
        radius = 5;
    break;
    case R.id.Brush_10:
        radius = 10;
    break;
    case R.id.Brush_15:
        radius = 15;
    break;
    case R.id.Brush_20:
        radius = 20;
    break;
    case R.id.Save:

        Canvas c = new Canvas(MainActivity.yourSelectedImage);
        for(int i = 0; i<whatYouEdit.size();i++){
            c.drawCircle(whatYouEdit.get(i).getX() , whatYouEdit.get(i).getY(), 
                    whatYouEdit.get(i).getRadius(), whatYouEdit.get(i).getPaint());
        }

        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), MainActivity.yourSelectedImage,
            "new pics", "mohahhaa");

    break;
    case R.id.Clear :
        whatYouEdit.clear();
    break;

    case R.id.Send :
        //new SendPicture().execute(MainActivity.yourSelectedImage);
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("text/html");
        sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("http://google.se/"));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Share it using:"));
        break;
    }
    return false;
}


/***
 * When you touch the screen it saves the x- and y-coordinates in the painting class together with the radius
 *  and the paint color.
 */
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        whatYouEdit.add(new painting(x,y,radius,paint));
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        whatYouEdit.add(new painting(x,y,radius,paint));
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        whatYouEdit.add(new painting(x,y,radius,paint));
        break;
    }

    return true;
}

/***
 * 
 * @author Andreas Angin
 *
 */

public class EditView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

    Thread thread = null;
    SurfaceHolder holder;

    public EditView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        holder = getHolder();
    }


    /***
     * Paints all that you've done on the screen.
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(true){
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;

            Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            MainActivity.yourSelectedImage=getResizedBitmap(MainActivity.yourSelectedImage,this.getHeight(),this.getWidth());
            canvas.drawBitmap(MainActivity.yourSelectedImage,0,0,new Paint());
            for(int i = 0; i<whatYouEdit.size();i++){
                canvas.drawCircle(whatYouEdit.get(i).getX() , whatYouEdit.get(i).getY(), 
                        whatYouEdit.get(i).getRadius(), whatYouEdit.get(i).getPaint());
            }

            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }



    private Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {

        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();

        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);

        return resizedBitmap;

    }

    /***
     * starts the thread you're painting on.
     */
    public void Start() {

        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();

    }
}
```

}

in the onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) method on case R.id.Send i like to put an url that links to a page with only the picture.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for your own server then just do a httppost to a location on your server (you will need some simple php to do this (see links below) - have a known name (either based off a UUID or a name given by the user) store the name locally on your device and upload it with that name, if your post works then the image will be there and you will know where you put it.

If you don't want to store the names locally on your device, you can store the names in a mysql database or a file in that directory, simply access the db or file and retrieve the list of names, and that will be the names of the images!

for generating a UUID in android its simply

UUID.randomUUID().toString(); (you could use just a subset of this number)

Links for uploading an image:
[Sending images using Http Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935946/sending-images-using-http-post)

http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/03/09/android/android-upload-image-to-server/

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/25/android-upload-an-image-to-a-server/

http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/