# Error in AsynTask on File Type

Tags: android, rest, android-asynctask, apache-httpclient-4.x

Im trying to send an image to a REST service using [Sending images using Http Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935946/sending-images-using-http-post). The post is quit informative but i get a compiling error at `FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file);`.

Error: `The constructor FileBody(File[]) is undefined`

Which is weird because i define it, why is this happenig and whats the solution to fixing it?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Code Source:

```
private class ImageUpload extends AsyncTask<File, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            if (checkNullState() == false) {
                showMyDialog();
            }
        }

        protected String doInBackground(File... file) {

            String imageDescriptionTemp = "Photo Temp Description.";
            String PostRequestUri = "https://demo.relocationmw.com/ws_docmgmt/Service1.svc";
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(PostRequestUri);
            FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file);
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            entity.addPart("Image", bin1);
            post.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            resEntity = response.getEntity();
            final String response_string = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            if(resEntity != null){
            Log.i("RESPONSE", response_string); 
            }else{
            return null;}
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (checkNullState() == true) {
                dismissMyDialog();
            }
            // add location once we have that figured out.
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Image can be viewed {Location}",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Map... values) {
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you want is

```
FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file[0]);
```

beacuse `doInBackground` uses [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html). So the following line of code:

```
doInBackground(Params... params)
```

is equivalent to

```
doInBackground(Params[] params)
```

and when you do

```
FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file)
```

`file` is an array (And I suppose that you have defined the constructor like this `FileBody(File file)`)

Comment: i get this error: Description Resource Path Location Type
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody HomeActivity.java /TestingApp/src/com/testingapp line 269 Java Problem

Comment: I forgot to wrap it with a Try/Catch. My bad. Thanks for the Help!