# App where users can send images to each other

Tags: android

I am thinking about making an android app in which you can send pictures to your contacts (grabbed from you address book). Sort of what the app WhatsApp does.
I was wondering, how is something like that achieved? I mean what would be the general design for it?

Any help/tip is appreciated

Thank you

EDIT: As a clarification, I am not looking for general answer of how to do this app from A to Z. I want to know specifically of the design architecture in terms how to link to users together using phone number. Would I have a server that stores all phone numbers of my users? Or is there som android functionality that can piggy back on phone number

Comment: Can you break this down into a more concrete question? As it stands, you're more asking "how can I make an app", which is likely to get closed. The better way is to ask a specific question that you run into while you're working on it.

Comment: My question is really about the architecture Ishould be using. Should I have a server, cloud or is it p2p? The general design and then  then I would dig into details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should know:

1. how to use push notifications: how to wait for incoming message from another user.
   how to use and handle those boardcasts.
   (read this - https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).
2. how you gonna send those pics? convert them to Base64 and send? or what?
   (read this - [Sending images using Http Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935946/sending-images-using-http-post)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This help but how would I link one user to another. I mean how would I map a phone number to an (ip address ?) ?

Comment: read this please: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html