# How to upload the multiple images into Image Server

Tags: android, file-upload

Which is best way to upload the image into the server from android? I need to upload the multiple images into the specific folder and path to be returned from the server.

Comment: can you please some code samples of things you have tried?

Comment: What is an Image Server in your case? If it's just a regular server, is FTP an option? You can even post it via HTTP if you have a web service to consume it.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend you to use Square's Tape while your uploading *multiple* files/images at once looking at the ease of use, efficiency,error handling, queuing system. If you are using only one file at time try to use any of [multi-part file upload](http://bit.ly/1j1Jdop) in any [android Http clients](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html)

This is what [**Square's Tape**](http://square.github.io/tape/):

> Tape is a collection of queue-related classes for Android and Java by
>   Square, Inc.
>
> QueueFile is a lightning-fast, transactional, file-based FIFO.
>   Addition and removal from an instance is an O(1) operation and is
>   atomic. Writes are synchronous; data will be written to disk before an
>   operation returns. The underlying file is structured to survive
>   process and even system crashes and if an I/O exception is thrown
>   during a mutating change, the change is aborted.
>
> An ObjectQueue represents an ordering of arbitrary objects which can
>   be backed either by the filesystem (via QueueFile) or in memory only.
>
> TaskQueue is a special object queue which holds Tasks, objects which
>   have a notion of being executed. Instances are managed by an external
>   executor which prepares and executes enqueued tasks.

Comment: can you provide any sample on how to implement it. Didn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

You can find many many examples online to do that. Anyway, the way I do that is using [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2937140/812598

Good luck!