# Upload Picture Form Fails On Mobile Chrome

Tags: android, codeigniter, file-upload, forms, image-capture

I'm building a mobile webapp, in which pictures from the user's phone play a significant part.

I've got this form, in which a user can upload a picture taken from his mobile phone into the app's DB. I'm using [CodeIgniter's upload class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) in order to do the actual uploading.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="myapp/do_upload" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" name="userfile"></input>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-block"></button>
    </form>
```

**PROBLEM:**

The app works great on my desktop computer: You choose a file, it uploads it, and throws an error if it doesn't work.

However, when trying to do the same thing on my mobile phone (Android running Mobile Chrome), the submit button refuses to work.

I've tried fiddling with the attributes - no success.

Any Idea what's stopping the form from actually working?

Comment: on what version of android are you testing this?

Comment: it seems like more of a browser issue to me

Comment: 4.1.2. I thibk Venus is right btw.

Comment: Can you please give me the link of your site?

Comment: browser issue clearly. Check this out: http://viljamis.com/blog/2012/file-upload-support-on-mobile/  and 
http://www.appypie.com/faqs/doesnt-the-default-browser-on-android-4-4-kit-kat-support-input-typefile-field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Problem is here

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="myapp/do_upload" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" name="userfile"></input>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-block"></button> //wrong
            <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-block"></button> //right
    </form>
```

Comment: Check this thread, if you are still stuck. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview

Comment: `<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-block"></input>` might also fix the problem. Broken markup is a poor start.

Comment: do I get the bounty or not ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if the filetype that you are trying to upload via mobile is in allowed_types?

If you did, can you please post what you get from:

```
var_dump($this->upload->data());
```

Comment: I did indeed. I'm trying to upload a jpg file and jpg is listed in `allowd_types`.

Comment: can you please post what you get from $this->upload->data()? You will get an array with some info, one of those is a "file_type" string. This way, you can see what type your server is receiving. Then, check if this type is in your mimes.php (in config folder).

Comment: Problem is - the form won't submit at all! It never gets to the actual upload script, but rather gets stuck on the form itself. The PHP function that handles the upload is never called - the submit button won't send me anywhere if a a file has been loaded into it.

Comment: That's really weird.. Are you using RewriteEngine to remove the file extension of the URL?? If you dont, try to put .php in your form action.

Comment: I'm uding codeigniter, and do_upload is. Method inside the money controller. How's adding .php gonna help here?

Comment: oh,my bad.. Im sorry. did you checked your routes file? can you access this method directly?

Comment: Sute can, either via adress bar or link

Comment: Sorry, but I think I cant help you.. You should start a bounty, I cant say if it's a problem with your server.

Comment: Maybe this can help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935946/sending-images-using-http-post/2937140#2937140