# php POST does not work when web site accessed from android device

Tags: php, android, post

My website is based on standard HTML, javascript and PHP code.
It is currently hosted on a remote web site hosting vendor.
When I access my website from my window PC, the PHP POST process works perfectly well.
When I access my website from my android cellphone or tablet, the POST process does not work at all.

```
var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], $_POST);
```

reveals that a GET is being received instead. Therefore, none of the form field values is being sent/received along with the request.

Here is my form tag:

```
<form id="am_form" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I tried step by step, removing the `id=` tag, then the `enctype=`, then the `action=` tag...  without success.

Since I can not streamline the statement any further, I don't know where to look for.

If anyone can help on why this is happening, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Correction: my current form tag is the following:

Comment: Check for this thread, it might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745291/upload-picture-form-fails-on-mobile-chrome

Comment: <form id="am_form" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: My complete form tag is the following:

Comment: Based on the suggested thread above (26745291), I progressively reviewed and cleaned all tags included in my form.  Unfortunately, the issue remains.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Problem resolved: A function was fired on click of the submit button. A statement in this function was setting the submit button to disabled.  By removing this statement, the submit PHP-POST process follows its normal course on the server...