# Socket is closed - Android AsyncTask

Tags: android, sockets

I have problem with receiving response from server. My app takes picture, sends it to server and waits for response. Unfortunately I get `socket is closed exception` whenever I try to receive response in `Inputstream`. I am struggling with this for 2 days. I wast trying different types of `Input` and `Output` streams but I have no idea whi this is happening. I was trying different solutions from other similar topics but none of them works. I am not good in Android because this is one of my first apps.

Comment: Well, is the server running and accepting incoming connections?

Comment: server is written in c#. Server is running, receiving sended image and it also is sending response

Comment: a. what protocol are you using
b. did you include the required permission in the manifest

Comment: `Community help me please. Thank you.`. In short you will delete this post like you did with several the last days?

Answer (score 1):

> [`OutputSteam#close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#close())
>
> Closes this output stream **and releases any system resources associated
>   with this stream**

You are closing the OutputSteam before getting the InputStream (which is where the error is thrown.

I'd recommend closing your socket and streams in the `finally` block.

Comment: if I comment `outputstream` there is weird situation that nothing is happening - image is not sent and nothing is shown in Logcat

Comment: I didn't say remove the OutputSteam, you obviously need it to write out the byte array of the image. I simply said don't close the stream prematurely.

Comment: ok, please check updated code because if you mean something like that it doesn't work and by saying this I mean that nothing is happening - image is not sent and Logcat is empty

Comment: Okay, no exception is a good thing, then, right? How have you checked that data is/isn't being received by the server?

Comment: Also, sockets seem very low-level... certainly you could send an HTTP Multipart Entity, no? Like [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935946/sending-images-using-http-post), maybe?

Comment: I am sending picture to c# server and then displaying it on picturebox, and it that case nothing is happening, but if I take picture and after that close client image is sent to server.... its weird

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. Don't have much experience with C#. I was reading this post about Camera uploading. Perhaps you could get some use out of it. http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/

Comment: I don't think so that problem is on C# side because with c# client - server evrything works fine

Comment: You could try a simpler Socket application with Android. Just try to send and receive a string. You might discover the problem then. Then think of adding in the image as the "next step".

Comment: ok, new information ! If I use synchronous server image is sent without closing the client application. If I use asynchronous server I have to close application to send image so it look likes that problem is in asynchronous server

Comment: ok, it's working, I had to close outputstream before creating `InputStream` by using this: `socket.shutdownOutput();`

Comment: I'm not sure why that would work. I've written several codes where I get both the streams and can use them without that method. For example,   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

Answer (score 0):

java.net.SocketException arises only when u close the OutputStream (or) Socket before reading from the server.so check your code